# Fuel SDK documentation Python

Tags: fuel-sdk, python

I am looking for documentation for the FUEL SDK.  I have found a number of examples and the following link:[FuelSDK](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/python/getting-started-with-the-python-sdk.html) but I have not found a complete set of SDK documentation does it exist?  If so could someone point me to it?

Thank you,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Refer [FuelSDK-Python](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python) documentation on GitHub.

It provides step by step process to install and configure SDK with code samples.

For other requests like **Campaign creation** etc you can refer [samples of Fuel SDK for Python](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/campaigns/campaign-create.html#pythonget)